# Enterprise Version Inventory for Adobe Reader 7,8,9,10

Tags: batch-file, adobe-reader

Is there a tool or method to build an inventory of the version of Adobe Reader installed on computers in a domain?

This would allow specific targeting of Adobe Reader updates to the computers who needed it, say from version 9 to version 10.

- If I deployed an Adobe Reader X MSI to all computers, would the MSI continue to be transferred to each computer every day where the MSI checks the version of Adobe Reader installed?
- Is there a different method GPO software installations use to check the version before transferring the MSI files over the network and installing them?
- Is the MSI file cached on the computer?

Answer (score 2):

How many installations are you talking about?

You can build an inventory using the psinfo.exe and findstr.exe commands from Microsoft:

```
psinfo.exe  \\computername -s  | findstr.exe -i "adobe" > computername.txt
```

Output:

```
Adobe AIR 1.5.0.7220
Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX 11.0.1.152
Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin 11.0.1.152
Adobe Reader 9.4.6 9.4.6
```

From there you can group a list of people who need an upgrade.

Possible next steps:

- If just a few people, visit their desk and install
- If more than just a few, publish an app via a GPO, and send an email to manually launch.  Then audit and repeat.
- If lots, set the GPO to push

You may want to invest some time in a CMDB like [Open-Audit](http://www.open-audit.org/) and auditing will not be an issue.